# Run TOR relay with ipv6 only ("DualStack Lite")

Tags: relays, network-configuration

I am a unfortunate customer of a provider that uses a so-called *DualStack Lite* (I can't post more than two URLs - check Wikipedia for detailed information on *DualStack Lite*). Short: My router can't be reached via `ipv4` easily. After I've switched to the new provider (I didn't realize the consequences) my TOR relay quit working (it's still configured with `ipv4`-ports only, so it's clear why it can't work). [This howto](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/IPv6RelayHowto) says that it's not yet possible to run a `ipv6`-only TOR relay.

- I understand that I can't run the relay with the DualStack Lite *natively* (as opposed to the outlined workaround below) - is that correct?
- Is it possible to use a [service like this](http://www.static-access.net/dslite-ipv6-portmapper/universal-portmappers/) to work around the limitations and run a TOR relay?

I assume that the answer to the latter question will be *no* because - as I understand - my relay registers itself at some TOR database with an outgoing `ipv4` address and the configured `ipv4` ports. If using a `ipv4` -> `ipv6` portmapper, a specific URL is used - one the TOR relay doesn't know about. Thus I think it's not possible for other TOR clients/relays to connect to my TOR relay.

However, if the answer to the latter question indeed *is* yes, could someone provide some *howto* or more detailed information about how to configure that (I didn't find anyting yet)?

Comment: From the looks of it, your v4 traffic is going through NAT, which would mean you can't receive inbound v4 connections. Unless your ISP allows you to reserve some v4 accessible port, this won't work currently. v6 is still too much of a rarity and can segment the network (harm anonymity).

Comment: Yes, my TOR relay is behind a NAT. I think that at least in Europe (we've got less IPv4 addresses per person then e.g. the US) ISPs slowly switch to IPv6-only routing (and provide a rather rudimentary IPv4 routing-support). While for most users that doesn't cause a problem, for TOR relays it apparently does.

Comment: You can still contribute to the network by setting up an IPv6 bridge - which helps much to a censored user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it will not work. You need to have an ipv4 address. Only (full) dual-stack provides both ipv6 and ipv4.

DualStack Lite (very common in Germany) means you have only a native ipv6 address, although through your provider you can make outgoing ipv4 requests. The other server will see an ipv4 address and can respond to it.

The opposite is not true: You do not have a public ipv4 address, but only a public ipv6 address. That is why you can only receive incoming requests over ipv6. Because of this limitation, it is called "Lite".

Some provides in Germany allow new (ipv6 only) customers to get an ipv4 address, but it will cost extra (e.g., MNet charges around 5 Euro per month).